# How to Imitate This Enumerate Display

Tags: enumerate, customize

I would like to imitate the following enumerate display:

[image]

Notice the enlarged item numbers, their color, the lack of a period following the item number, how they start a little below the top of the first line of the item's content, and how the item number spans two lines of output.

QUESTION: How may I modify the following code which contains an enumerate spanning multiple pages, in order to mimic the above display?

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\textwidth 3.85in
\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item There is no excuse for those who could be scholars and are not.
\item Study. Obedience: non multa, sed multum — not many things, but well.
\item There is no excuse for those who could be scholars and are not.
\chapter{}
\item Study. Obedience: non multa, sed multum — not many things, but well.
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your items ought to have at least two lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\newlist{advice}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[advice]{
  label=\formatadvicenumber{\arabic*},
  ref=\arabic*,
  leftmargin=4em,
  resume,
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\formatadvicenumber}{m}{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\LARGE #1}%
}

\setlength{\textwidth}{3.85in}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\begin{advice}
\item There is no excuse for those who could be scholars and are not.
\item Study. Obedience: non multa, sed multum — not many things, but well.
\item There is no excuse for those who could be scholars and are not.
\end{advice}

\chapter{}

\begin{advice}
\item Study. Obedience: non multa, sed multum — not many things, but well.
\item
\item
\end{advice}

\end{document}
```

I use `resume` because having `\chapter` inside a list is very disputable.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks egreg. A quick question if I may---One does not need to load the `xparse` package in order to make use of `NewDocumentCommand`? Thanks again.

Comment: @mlchristians Not with a recent (from October 2020) version of LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you again.